# Generate dict object from Jinja2 template

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2

Can i get object tree (dict for example) from jinja2-like string?

Is there a method to extract tree from Enviromet/Template jinja2 object?
Or we need parse string manually?

For example:

```
s = '''
{% for item in items %} 
    {{ item.one }} 
    {{ item.two }}
    {{ item.two.some }} 
{% endfor %} 
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.name }}
    {% for friend in user.friends %} 
        {{ friend.name }} 
        {{ friend.age }} 
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
'''
```

Expected output:

```
tree = {
    'items': [
        {
            'one': type,  # any type
            'two': {
                'some': type
            }
        }
    ],
    'users': [
        {
            'name': type,
            'friends': [
                {
                    'name': type,
                    'age': type
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What was the actual output, and how was it different from the one you expected?

Comment: @ForceBru I didn't get the actual result, Expected output in question is an example of what might have been